# How to describe a three-dimensional space of points where all nearest neighbour points are unit distance apart?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I want to describe a project where I set out to construct a three-dimensional (geometric) space of points where all nearest neighbour points are unit distance apart (I’m aware, of course, that this is not naively possible).

How do I best refer to such a space, and are there more appropriate/correct terms than those I have used in my question?

Sorry this is basic, but thanks for any help.

Comment: [unit distance graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph) in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I don't think unit distance graphs specify points to be unit distance apart from all adjacent points? But thanks for comment.